# Rowspan not working as expected

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am trying to create a table layout as shown in below image:
[image]

Below is my Html code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Table sketch</title>
    <style>
        table {
            table-layout: fixed;
            width: 20em;
        }
        td {
            width: 4em;
            height: 1.5em;
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4">&nbsp;1&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;2&nbsp;</td>
            <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;3&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">&nbsp;4&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;5&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;6&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4">&nbsp;7&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

But it generates below layout:

[image]

When I change rowspan value from 2 to 3 for second row. It gives me right layout.

```
<tr>
    <td rowspan="3">&nbsp;2&nbsp;</td>
    <td rowspan="3">&nbsp;3&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
```

Here is a [link](http://jsbin.com/hoqibuyuri/edit?html,output) to jsbin.

But why is first html code not working?
Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have one `tr` tag too much: The second row has to contain 3 elements (i.e. no separate `tr` for the third element in that row):

```css
table {
            table-layout: fixed;
            width: 20em;
        }
        td {
            width: 4em;
            height: 1.5em;
            text-align: center;
        }
```

```html
<body>
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4">&nbsp;1&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;2&nbsp;</td>
            <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;3&nbsp;</td>
            <td colspan="2">&nbsp;4&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;5&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;6&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4">&nbsp;7&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```